# Google API Playground Calendar Events Watch API error 400 "parseError"

Tags: google-api, elixir, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I am trying to watch some calendar events via API. I am having trouble with getting this to work though. I had been thinking it might have been the library I'm using (https://hex.pm/packages/google_api_calendar)

But I had recently tried using Google oAuth playground to try the same and that had not been working either.[image: OAuth 2.0 Playground /events/watch request 400 parseError.]

So I think I might not fundamentally understand something about watching calendar events. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation of [Google Calendar API Events:watch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/watch), you have to provide a request body with the following structure:

```
{
  "id": string,
  "token": string,
  "type": string,
  "address": string,
  "params": {
    "ttl": string
  }
}
```

[image]

### Further Reading:

- [Guide: Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push)